# How to pass values from one window to another PyQT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a PyQT5 webscraper program that uses two windows. The second window is a config window in which you enter the url to scrape, however I have no idea how to actually return the url so the main window has access to it.

```
class SpiderConfWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_SpiderSettings):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_SpiderSettings()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnConfirm.clicked.connect(self.confirm)

    def confirm(self):
        return self.ui.entryUrl.text()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.spider_conf_w = SpiderConfWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.url = None
        self.ui.btnSpiderSettings.triggered.connect(self.spider_settings)

    def spider_settings(self):
        self.spider_conf_w.show()
```

I want `SpiderConfWindow.confirm` to set `MainWindow`'s url attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do send data across widgets is to use Qt's signals and slots mechanism.

Once you have everything appropriately hooked up, an **event** (like clicking `SpiderConfWindow`'s button) will trigger the emission of a **signal** containing some data. This signal will be handled by a **slot** - likely a method in your `MainWindow` class that know how to deal with the data.

Since I don't have access to the code of your GUI, here's an alternative minimal example showcasing this behavior. The `SubWindow` widget spawns when clicking the button in the `MainWindow` widget, and then emits its `submitClicked` signal (a string) when the submit button is clicked. This signal is connected to the `MainWindow`'s `on_sub_window_confirm`, which works as the slot that deals with the incoming data.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw


class SubWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    submitClicked = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)  # <-- This is the sub window's signal
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.line_edit = qtw.QLineEdit(placeholderText="Enter URL here:")
        self.btn = qtw.QPushButton("Submit")
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.confirm)

    def confirm(self):  # <-- Here, the signal is emitted *along with the data we want*
        self.submitClicked.emit(self.line_edit.text())
        self.close()


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.sub_window = None  # placeholder attribute for the sub window
        layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.label = qtw.QLabel("Current URL: None")
        self.btn = qtw.QPushButton("Get new URL...")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.show_sub_window)

    def show_sub_window(self):  # <-- Here, we create *and connect* the sub window's signal to the main window's slot
        self.sub_window = SubWindow()
        self.sub_window.submitClicked.connect(self.on_sub_window_confirm)
        self.sub_window.show()
    
    def on_sub_window_confirm(self, url):  # <-- This is the main window's slot
        self.label.setText(f"Current URL: {url}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MainWindow()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```